# Fieldref - open in new window

Tags: xml, elements-xml

I want to know how to make in SharePoint so that a link by FieldRef opens in new window.

I have got some column and one with a link which opens, but only the same window. Sharepoint 2013

```
<View Name="{493AB563-3F2C-4539-B1D6-6ED063F7EA1F}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Wszystkie dokumenty" Url="/certyfikaty_autoryzacje/Certyfikaty Pracownikw/Forms/AllItems.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/dlicon.png?rev=23" ><Query><GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"><FieldRef Name="Wystawca_x0020_Certyfikatu"/></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Pracownik"/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Edit"/><FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/><FieldRef Name="Wystawca_x0020_Certyfikatu"/><FieldRef Name="Pe_x0142_na_x0020_Nazwa_x0020_Certyfikatu"/><FieldRef Name="Pracownik"/><FieldRef Name="Data_x0020_Wystawienia"/><FieldRef Name="Data_x0020_Wyga_x015b_ni_x0119_cia"/><FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"/><FieldRef Name="Link"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">50</RowLimit><Aggregations Value="Off"/><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
```

Comment: Post relevant code

Comment: I added a code I want to get link column called name.

Comment: Check if this helps http://www.andrewconnell.com/Adding-OpenInNewWindow-option-to-SharePoint-Links-lists

Comment: But how made patern to this coumn ? please help

Comment: I don't know XML language